# Contract examples

Tags: contracts, guidance, business

Can anyone provide some basic contract examples that you work under?  I am in the difficult position of exiting an internship.  I am at the point where I am just doing work, not sitting in on sessions or actively learning.

So I feel like I should be paid for my time.  Verbally, the studio has agreed to pay me on projects. ** I must say, at this point, that the studio has never backed out of a payment.  They always pay me the agreed price in a timely and fair manner **  The problem problem I am running into is that there is no clear and defined contract that states what I am actually doing.

I agree to a project thinking I am just cutting an element (BGs, FX, Sound Design...etc).  Then I get "Where are we with the Foley?" or "Ok, your going to do ALL of the cutting and supervising and I'll mix".  I feel very taken advantage of and it just needs to stop.  Preferably without having to sever these relationships.

Sorry for the long winded post, but I'm terrible at the business stuff and I am seriously in need of some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer the question you're asking about contract, but you may want to look at this thread from a few months ago:  [What do you say when a client asks for more?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3762/what-do-you-say-when-a-client-asks-for-more)

There is some useful advice in there that I think applies to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the US, email me and I can help you put together a contract. 
Viptampa(at)gmail.com